# Convert HTTP response to JSON in Ruby

Tags: ruby, json

I'm doing a GET request and getting this response:

```
"oauth_token=USYS96A708CACBDA9C74322DAB41A53CA_idses-int02.a.fsglobal.net&oauth_token_secret=09c8b05b874fac29b4e542c388cb3f&oauth_callback_confirmed=true"
```

How can I convert this to JSON in Ruby?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Step 1: Parse the GET response:

```
require 'cgi'

CGI::parse(MYSTRING)
```

Returns: `{"param1"=>["value1"], "param2"=>["value2"], "param3"=>["value3"]}`

Step 2. [Convert to JSON](http://www.rexfeng.com/blog/2012/12/convert-a-ruby-hash-into-valid-json/):

```
require 'json'

myObject.to_json
```

Alternatively, look at this snippet:

https://gist.github.com/timsavery/1657351

```
require "rubygems"
require "json"
require "net/http"
require "uri"

uri = URI.parse("http://api.sejmometr.pl/posiedzenia/BZfWZ/projekty")

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)

response = http.request(request)

if response.code == "200"
  result = JSON.parse(response.body)

  result.each do |doc|
    puts doc["id"] #reference properties like this
    puts doc # this is the result in object form
    puts ""
    puts ""
  end
else
  puts "ERROR!!!"
end
```

Comment: a smaller in code size for getting response `result = JSON.parse(Net::HTTP.get(URI("whatever url you're using")))`
if there's a parse error, then result will be `nil` and can skip the .each with simple if